# Converting from string to blob and sending email along with attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, attachment, contenttype

I have this method

```
public void sendEmailWithAttachment(){

        Blob b;
        String b64;
        String strUrlUTF8;
        String sampleString=generateReport();  //call generateReport method to get string
        System.debug('[Original sample string]'+sampleString);

        strUrlUTF8 = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(sampleString, 'UTF-8');
        System.debug('String strUrlUTF8: [' + strUrlUTF8 + ']');

        b = Blob.valueOf(strUrlUTF8);
        System.debug('Blob b: [' + b.toString() + ']');

        //b64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b);
        //System.debug('String b64: [' + b64 + ']');

         //b = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(b64);
        //System.debug('Blob b: [' + b.toString() + ']');
        Document doc= new Document();
        Folder reportFolder = [select id from Folder where name = 'Partner Monthly Report' limit 1];
        if(reportFolder.id != null){
            doc.FolderId = reportFolder.id ;
        }
        doc.name=Monthandyear+'-'+'Partner Monthly Report';
        doc.body=b;
        insert doc;        
        String[] toaddress;                 //String array to hold the email addresses
        User usr=[SELECT id,Name,Email FROM User WHERE Name='sample' LIMIT 1];
        if(usr.Email != null){
            toaddress=new String[]{usr.Email}; 
        }
        EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'Reporttemplate' LIMIT 1];
        // Create the email attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            efa.setContentType('application/pdf');
            efa.setFileName(Monthandyear+'-'+'Partner Mothly Report.pdf');
            efa.setBody(b);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();    
            msg.setTemplateId(template.Id);
            msg.setToAddresses(toaddress);
            if(usr.id != null){
                msg.setTargetObjectId(usr.id); //  Here you can give Id of  User , Lead , Contact 
            }
            msg.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            msg.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileattachment[]{efa});
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { msg });  

    }
```

generateReport() method

```
 public String generateReport(){ 
        String reportContent='';
        reportContent += '<table align="right"><tr><td align="right">width="140" height="100"/></td></tr></table><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>';
        reportContent += '<center><table align="center" width="70%" height="60%" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#819FF7;"><tr><td ><b>Partner Monthly Report</b></td></tr></table></center><br></br>';

        reportContent += '<center><table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#FBFBEF;height:60%;width:70%;">';
        reportContent += '<tr ><td align="left" style="background-color:#819FF7;"><b>Cumulative Data for the month &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+Month+'</b></td>';                
        reportContent += '<td align="right" style="background-color:#819FF7;"><b>Total Values (in Rupees)</b></td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Cumulative Disbursement</td><td align="right">'+cumulDisbursement+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Cumulative Repayment</td><td align="right">'+cumulRepayment+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Cumulative outstanding</td><td align="right">'+cumulOutstanding+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Disbursement </td><td align="right">'+disbursementLoanTranche+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Repayment collected</td><td align="right">'+repaymentCollected+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Principal Paid</td><td align="right">'+prinicpalPaid+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Interest Paid </td><td align="right">'+interestPaid+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Repayment Rate %</td><td align="right">'+repaymentRate+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Service Fee</td><td align="right">'+serviceFeeLoanTranche+'</td></tr></table><center>';
        reportContent += '<center><table border="" align="center" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#819FF7;height:60%;width:70%;">';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="center"><b>Bank Balance</b></td></tr></table></center>';
        reportContent += '<center><table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#FBFBEF;height:40%;width:70%;">';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left" width="76%">Axis Bank</td><td align="right">'+axisBankBalance +'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">DBS Bank</td><td align="right">'+dbsBankBalance+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="right"><b>Total:&nbsp;</b></td><td align="right">'+totalBankBalance+'</td></tr></table>';                
        reportContent += '<table border="" align="center" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#819FF7;height:60%;width:70%;">';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="center"><b>Funds available for lending</b></td></tr></table></center>';                                   
        reportContent += '<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#FBFBEF;height:20%;width:70%;">';  
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left" width="76%">Bank Balance</td><td align="right">'+totalBankBalance+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Expected repayment</td><td align="right">'+expectedRepayment+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="left">Less: Lender Repayment(Yunus and other)</td><td align="right">'+lenderRepaymentBalance+'</td></tr>';
        reportContent += '<tr><td align="right"><b>Total:&nbsp;</b></td><td align="right">'+overallTotalBalance+'</td></tr></table><br></br></center>';
        return reportContent;
    }
```

The problem is i am not able to open the pdf file. It says
**Adobe Reader could not open '11-07-2014-Partner Monthly Report.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged(for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)**
Please give any suggestion how to achieve this

Comment: Please look at this workaround and give it a try

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/how-to-download-a-vf-page-as-pdf-and-email-it-from-a-trigger

Comment: Please try this approach 

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/how-to-download-a-vf-page-as-pdf-and-email-it-from-a-trigger

Answer (score 1):

This way it can never work. You can't just put html tags into a string, utf8-encode it and expect it to be a valid PDF... the html must be **converted** into the PDF format - which is not a trivial task.

The good news is that salesforce can do it for you! For the conversion you need a visualforce page. I will show you the concept, but not provide full source code.

Create a new vf-page call it MyPage and render it as PDF like this

```
<apex:page controller="YourController" renderas="pdf" >
    <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!YourHtml}" ></apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

To get you html in the page, you will have to use a controller (which should be a separate apex class). It has to provide a function

```
public with sharing class YourController  {
    public string getYourHtml() {
        return "Her comes <b>your Html</b>";
    }
}
```

Test you PDF by navigating to /apex/MyPage - this should be displayed as PDF.

Now you can grab the content of the page and use it as a blob and e.g. store it as attachment or send an email:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/MyPage');
pageRef.getParameters().put( "id", AnObjectId ); // use this to pass parameters to your Controller, e.g. an Id or whatever
Blob pdfBlob = pageRef.getContent();
```

Now if you are in a context which does not support getContent() please look at this workaround

[How to download a VF page as PDF and email it from a trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/how-to-download-a-vf-page-as-pdf-and-email-it-from-a-trigger)

Comment: I have followed this approach because i am using scheduler class to schedule the method to send mail and save the file in document folder. getContent() can't be used there.Any other suitable approach to achieve this?

Comment: You can't create the pdf without getContent(). Try to decouple the attachment creation from the actual sending, e.g. by precreating and saving all the pdfs earlier.

Comment: Found something which could help you. Look at the link in the bootom of my answer.

Comment: i do tried with apex rest api and future methods.It works fine but the only problem is i have to supply session id.And session id as i know gets expired every 30 min.I tried using this approach but when i m logged out of the instance it doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't there any direct way to achieve this functionality?I am struggling to do this from last 15 days.If not pdf can i save my file in word or excel and send that along with mail?

Comment: Excel will be even harder in my experience. In your case probably impossible because there is no zip functionality in apex. New versions of office-files are zipped xml. It can be parsed, created, modified (the hard way). Usually the missing zip capabilities are a circumvented by a javascript library - but in your case you have no javascript available in batch-context.

Comment: If it is not automated then there is no problem.I tried with rest api class and future method but again there was problem of session id.